# Python code to determine distance to specific polygon boundary

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, proximity

I am trying to automate a process to assign location codes to parcels.  The method is to measure from the centroid of the parcel polygon to the eastern edge of the section polygon, then measure from the same centroid to the northern edge.  The order is important.

I was looking at the PointDistance_analysis tool/command, but since the points in question lie within the polygon edges that I am measuring to, it won't return a viable number.  In addition, I have been unable to determine how to tell it to measure to a specific polygon side.

Doing this manually is simple and takes about 2 minutes per parcel.  However, I have almost 100,000 parcels to do, so an automated process would be preferred.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a picture that illustrates what you are try to describe in words, please?  I suspect you will need to create temporary lines from the part of the polygon boundary that you want to get the distances to, and then use Near on them.

Comment: Turn your polygons into lines. Then try the point tool.

Comment: Doing the line conversion seems to be the way to go. It's just going to be cumbersome. Within the loop, I'll have to convert polygons to lines, get my measurements, then convert back to polygons.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, folks. I appreciate the help.